# Can hide HTML elements with .onclick Javascript Code?

Tags: javascript

I have main sections of my HTML page that I want to hide when I click certain nav links. Example, if I click the about section of the page, I'd like to hide the projects/skills sections.

This is my javascript - the Home/about/projects/skills are linked to the ID of the main HTML sections.

The abt/prj/ski are linked to the a elements to navigate up and down the site.

Any ideas why the code above will not work?

```js
let home = document.getElementById('home');
let about = document.getElementById('about');
let projects = document.getElementById('projects');
let skills = document.getElementById('skills');

let abt = document.getElementById('abt');
let prj = document.getElementById('prj');
let ski = document.getElementById('ski');

// ---------------   Remove Child Project/Skills on link click

let hide = function(input) {
  if (input === 1) {
    projects.style.display = 'none';
    skills.style.display = 'none';
  } else if (input === 2) {
    about.style.display = 'none';
    skills.style.display = 'none';
  } else if (input === 3) {
    about.style.display = 'none';
    projects.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

abt.onclick = hide(1);
prj.onclick = hide(2);
ski.onclick = hide(3);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/style.css">
  <script src="./resources/js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header id="banner">
    <nav class="banner-right">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="abt">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="prj">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="" id="ski">Skills</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- About -->
  <section id="about">
  </section>

  <!-- Projects -->
  <section id="projects">
  </section>

  <!-- Skills -->
  <section id="skills">
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="contact">
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `abt.onclick = hide(1);` invokes the function and assigns its _return value_ (`undefined`) to the `onclick` property. What you meant was `abt.onclick = () => hide(1);`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is your onclick assignement.

When you're doing `abt.onclick = hide(1);` you're basically telling that onclick on the `abt` link. run the **result** of the function `hide(1)` (which is `undefined` !

To solve your problem try this instead :

```js
abt.onclick = () => hide(1);
```

Or whitout arrow functions

```js
abt.onclick = function(){
   hide(1);
}
```

Small example :

Here you can see that the hide function is running before even clicking on the button

```js
const workingButton = document.getElementById("working")
const notWorkingButton = document.getElementById("notWorking")

function hide(id){
  console.log(`Set display to none the content of div ${id}`)
  document.getElementById(`content${id}`).style.display = 'none'
}

workingButton.onclick = function(){
  hide(1);
}
notWorkingButton.onclick = hide(2);
```

```html
<div id="content1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pulvinar sodales mauris, facilisis lobortis ligula venenatis vitae. Sed pulvinar elit magna, vel accumsan lacus bibendum auctor. Nulla dictum, neque nec dapibus pharetra, ante nisl semper
    nunc, vel varius erat enim at lorem. Phasellus vestibulum orci eget porta sollicitudin. Nunc in nulla vel sapien posuere rhoncus ac vitae augue. Mauris quis felis eu dolor egestas mollis. Integer ut massa sed augue hendrerit blandit.
  </p>
</div>

<div id="content2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pulvinar sodales mauris, facilisis lobortis ligula venenatis vitae. Sed pulvinar elit magna, vel accumsan lacus bibendum auctor. Nulla dictum, neque nec dapibus pharetra, ante nisl semper
    nunc, vel varius erat enim at lorem. Phasellus vestibulum orci eget porta sollicitudin. Nunc in nulla vel sapien posuere rhoncus ac vitae augue. Mauris quis felis eu dolor egestas mollis. Integer ut massa sed augue hendrerit blandit.
  </p>
</div>

<button id="working">Working button</button>
<button id="notWorking">Not Working button</button>
```

In your case you should also remove the `href` attributes otherwise it will try to move to another page.

Fixed example :

```js
let home = document.getElementById('home');
let about = document.getElementById('about');
let projects = document.getElementById('projects');
let skills = document.getElementById('skills');

let abt = document.getElementById('abt');
let prj = document.getElementById('prj');
let ski = document.getElementById('ski');

// ---------------   Remove Child Project/Skills on link click

let hide = function(input) {
console.log(input)
  if (input === 1) {
    projects.style.display = 'none';
    skills.style.display = 'none';
  } else if (input === 2) {
    about.style.display = 'none';
    skills.style.display = 'none';
  } else if (input === 3) {
    about.style.display = 'none';
    projects.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

abt.onclick = () => hide(1);
prj.onclick = () => hide(2);
ski.onclick = () => hide(3);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/style.css">
  <script src="./resources/js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header id="banner">
    <nav class="banner-right">
      <ul>
        <li><a id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="abt">About</a></li>
        <li><a id="prj">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a id="ski">Skills</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- About -->
  <section id="about">
  </section>

  <!-- Projects -->
  <section id="projects">
    My projects
  </section>

  <!-- Skills -->
  <section id="skills">
      My Skills
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer id="contact">
     My Contacts
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No that still hasn't solved my issue. I've defined the hide function above, and i have used a similar JavaScript structure on previous projects in my online learning (codecademy).

Any other ideas?

Comment: I've update my example try now with the new snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think when you click on a tag, your HTML get refresh so change a tag to for example div tag

edit:

I make your code here and it is working.
I changed a little the three last function and the div that I told you about and a line of CSS to have a pointer cursor while you are using any tag of html

https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-frog-wui3x5?file=/index.html

Comment: I tried moving the ID from the a element to the li element, and two things happen:

I no longer have a visual prompt that a link exists from the mouse cursor changing when hovering over an a element.
It still does not resolve my issue :(

Comment: I put codes into a live link in codesandbox I think now it is clear and ok.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, yes I found my issues with your sandbox link. My script was in the wrong location in my html file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your script should be placed at the bottom of the document, or you can use `defer/async` attributes to start executing the script after creating the DOM tree
Placing it inside the head element must include `defer/async` attributes since it uses the DOM at loading time.

```html
<script src="./resources/js/script.js" defer></script>
```

```html
<script src="./resources/js/script.js" async></script>
```

2. you should prevent your links from reloading the webpage, use `javascript:void(0)`:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="abt">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="prj">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="ski">Skills</a></li>
</ul>
```

3. Notice here you are assigning the returned value from calling the `hide` function each time with a different number as argument

```js
abt.onclick = hide(1);
prj.onclick = hide(2);
ski.onclick = hide(3);
```

Your hide function:

```js
let hide = function(input) {
    if (input === 1) {
        projects.style.display = 'none';
        skills.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (input === 2) {
        about.style.display = 'none';
        skills.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (input === 3) {
        about.style.display = 'none';
        projects.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

so you should return a function insted here is how:

```js
let hide = function(input) {
  return function() {
    if (input === 1) {
        projects.style.display = 'none';
        skills.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (input === 2) {
        about.style.display = 'none';
        skills.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (input === 3) {
        about.style.display = 'none';
        projects.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Well, I have been thinking that you may need to toggle those sections, so only one is shown and the others stay hidden, so I made this code snippet

```js
document.querySelector(".banner-right").onclick = function(e) {
  document.querySelector("section.nav-section:not(.hidden)")?.classList.add("hidden");
  if(e.target.className.includes("nav-toggle")) {
    document.querySelector(`section#${e.target.getAttribute("data-section")}`).classList.remove("hidden");
  }
};
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
  <header id="banner">
    <nav class="banner-right">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" data-section="about">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" data-section="projects">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" data-section="skills">Skills</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<!-- About -->
<section id="about" class="nav-section hidden">
   about section
</section>

<!-- Projects -->
<section id="projects" class="nav-section hidden">
   projects section
</section>

<!-- Skills -->
<section id="skills" class="nav-section hidden">
   skills section
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer id="contact">    
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, use `e.preventDefault()` + add script to body

```
let hide = function(event,input) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (input === 1) {
        projects.style.display = 'none';
        skills.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (input === 2) {
        about.style.display = 'none';
        skills.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (input === 3) {
        about.style.display = 'none';
        projects.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

abt.onclick = (e)=>hide(e,1);
prj.onclick = (e)=>hide(e,2);
ski.onclick = (e)=>hide(e,3);
```